# Toggle disabled property on materialize dropdown selection?

Tags: jquery, html, materialize

I want to default a select in materialize as disabled.

```
<form>
 <select id="mySelect" required disabled>
  <option>Cats</option>
  <option>Dogs</option>
 </select>
</form>

<button id="try" >Try it</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#try').click(function(){
 $('#mySelect').prop("disabled", false);
};
```

In the dev tools it shows that the disabled property is removed on the select when the try button is clicked. However, the dropdown will not work. I believe this is something specific to materialize because it seems to dynamically generate a styled unordered list above my select. It adds the disabled to this newly generated list, which I removed as well.

Comment: so you mean that when the select is not disabled it's not working ?

Comment: @El Sam when the select is not disabled, it is working. when disabled is applied and then removed via an on click in javascript, it is not working.

Comment: Ok, try adding `$('select').material_select();` below `$('#mySelect').prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: @ElSam this worked! one more question. how would you set a default option for the dropdown when materialize generates it? if i add it into my code as such:
`<option class=""><span>(GMT -10:00) Hawaii</span></option><option class="active selected"><span>(GMT -08:00) Alaska</span></option>`

It is the incorrect option as the unordered list that is generated by materialize is the real option that needs to be targeted.

Comment: Glad it worked, I edited my previous answer to include my answer in the comment above, please check it as the answer.

Comment: as for your other question, please make another question thread, and I'll be glad to answer you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the `select` to work with Materializecss , you must add the following js line to your `script` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select').material_select();
});
```

And to make sure it works after enabling the `select` edit your js function as follow :

```
 $('#try').click(function(){
   $('#mySelect').prop("disabled", false);
   $('select').material_select();
});
```

Comment: it is the first line in my js. sorry, i forgot to mention that. i'm new to materialize.

Comment: awesome :D and usefull @ElSam

Answer (score 1):

To update the select, you need to re-initialize

```
$('#try').click(function(){
    $('#mySelect').prop("disabled", false);
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('#mySelect');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
};
```